# Garbage collecting object with long running thread

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

If there is an object with infinite loop, will it ever be garbage collected (while thread is running)?

I made a program to test this and it seems it will never be garbage collected, but I'd like someone with more experience to confirm this.

EDIT: I forgot to add example. Here is example which I have used.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WeakReference wr1 = InitializeClassWithLoop();
        WeakReference wr2 = InitializeClassWithoutLoop();

        GC.Collect(2);
        GC.Collect(2);
        GC.Collect(2);
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Thread.Sleep(30000);
        Console.WriteLine($"ClassWithLoop.IsAlive = {wr1.IsAlive}\nClassWithoutLoop.IsAlive = {wr2.IsAlive}\n");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static WeakReference InitializeClassWithLoop()
    {
        var cs = new ClassWithLoop();
        return new WeakReference(cs);
    }

    static WeakReference InitializeClassWithoutLoop()
    {
        var cs = new ClassWithoutLoop();
        return new WeakReference(cs);
    }
}

public class ClassWithLoop
{
    public ClassWithLoop()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(Loop);
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void Loop()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            counter++;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

public class ClassWithoutLoop
{
    int counter;

    public ClassWithoutLoop()
    {
        counter = 5;
    }
}
```

Result is:
ClassWithLoop.IsAlive = True
ClassWithoutLoop.IsAlive = False

Comment: Object used in infinite loop you mean?

Comment: are you using same object or creating new one on every loop?

Comment: what does "object with a loop" mean? an object will never be garbage collected as long as your process (no matter which thread) has a reference to that object.

Comment: Please provide some code to demonstrate what you are asking about.

Comment: @RenéVogt Correct me if I am wrong..  If we create new object on loop then the older objects will be collected right??

Comment: Only objects that are no longer referenced (e.g. no variable "points" to them) _can_ be garbage collected. Objects that are still referenced will not be collected. If you create new ones or not does not matter. _When_ exactly the (no longer referenced) objects get collected depends on other things like gc strategy and memory pressure.

Comment: @PowerStar, only if you remove all references to them and the garbage collector determines it needs to run.

Comment: @DavidArno removing all reference means not using the object right?

Comment: I repeat: if you would provide an [mcve] we may be able to give an exact answer.

Comment: @PowerStar, if for example, you have the line `var x = new SomeType();` in that loop and you do not assign `x` to anything else in the loop, then all those previous `SomeType`'s aren't referenced and so are eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: `Only objects that are no longer referenced (e.g. no variable "points" to them) can be garbage collected. ` Your main point is correct, although your bit in brackets less so. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cbrumme/2003/04/19/lifetime-gc-keepalive-handle-recycling/ may be of interest.

Comment: @RenéVogt it means object which starts thread with infinite loop.

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume you mean a class has a method with an infinite loop inside it:

```
public class A
{
  public void IDontEverEnd()
  {
    while(true) { }
  }
}
```

Assuming you then do something like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
  new A().IDontEverEnd();
})
```

Then your program will remain active, as this will just run on a separate thread, but **NO** it will not be garbage collected; this is because the call to `IDontEverEnd` never exits, and therefore the reference to the instance of `A` never falls out of use.

---

### EDIT

As mjwills mentions in the comments, it **is** possible sometimes for an item to be garbage collected, even if a method is being executed on it.

Though in practice, so long as you're not dealing with p/invoke stuff, chances are this won't matter to you.

Comment: As https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cbrumme/2003/04/19/lifetime-gc-keepalive-handle-recycling/ states `In other words, ‘this’ can be collected even while you are executing an instance method on that object.` It is rare that makes a meaningful difference, but something to be aware of.

Comment: @mjwills oh, that's interesting!